# Phoenix framework: Where does resource's default form @action attribute for all resources come from?

Tags: forms, phoenix-framework

The command

```
mix phx.gen.html Blog Post posts title body:text
```

generates among other files the template form.html.eex for the add/edit posts form, which looks like this:

```
<%= form_for @changeset, @action, fn f -> %>
  <%= if @changeset.action do %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      <p>Oops, something went wrong! Please check the errors below.</p>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label f, :title, class: "control-label" %>
    <%= text_input f, :title, class: "form-control" %>
    <%= error_tag f, :title %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label f, :body, class: "control-label" %>
    <%= textarea f, :body, class: "form-control" %>
    <%= error_tag f, :body %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The form_for function gets @action argument which is not present in the PostController, so where does it come from? I couldn't find.

In my installation I have a plug MyProject.Locale which redirects all unlocalized requests to localized ones like:

```
/posts --> /de/posts
```

And I have the :locale scope in my router

```
  scope "/:locale", MyProject.Web, as: :locale do
    pipe_through :browser
    get "/", PageController, :index
    resources "/posts", PostController        
  end
```

The default @action doesn't take the scope's locale chunk into account and sends the POST request to the /posts url, which is redirected by my MyProject.Locale plug to /de/posts as GET request (it uses the function Phoenix.Controller.redirect(to:...)). I want the form to send the POST request to the localized path.
So, can we override this @action argument for all resources somewhere in one place or do we have to provide it in each controller in render function call

```
render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset, action: action)
```

or the only option is to change the form templates for all resources?

Comment: "The form_for function gets @action argument which is not present in the PostController, so where does it come from? I couldn't find." The action should be there in the `new.html.eex`, `edit.html.eex`, etc templates in the same folder as `form.html.eex`.

Comment: @Dogbert, thanks! It's there, I've forgotten that in PostController the render function gets the new.html template and not form.html. Now it's clear that I will need to change new.html.eex and edit.html.eex for each resource.